# Warnings on too-small array sizes to functions in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, buffer-overrun

Are there any tools (preferably on linux) that can warn when an argument is defined as a smaller array then the prototype specifies?

eg:

```
void somefunc(float arg[10]);  /* normally this would be defined in a header */

void my_func(void)
{
    float arg[2];
    somefunc(arg);  /* <-- this could be a warning */
}
```

I realize this isn't invalid code but it could resolve some common mistakes if it were possible to warn of it (ran into one of these bugs recently).

Some tools (clang static checker for eg), will warn if the function is in the same file and sets a value outside the array bounds, but I was wondering if anything will warn if the arg is smaller then the prototype alone.

I've used cppcheck, clang, smatch, splint, gcc's -Wextra... but none complain of this.

Comment: Is this C or C++? The answers will be quite different depending on the language.

Comment: C (though would be interested to know if its possible in either C or C++)

Comment: Update: wrote a script to check for these cases, it uses clang to inspect the source so it does a reasonable good job. The script takes a C/C++ file, then defines and include paths -D, -I. For blender I setup a makefile target that runs it threaded on all our files with correct includes and defines.

Committed: 
http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2012-October/050282.html

Example of a fix that this script found but other static checkers missed: http://lists.blender.org/pipermail/bf-blender-cvs/2012-October/050280.html there were ~4 or so issues like this that the script found.

Comment: Update #2, cppcheck guys think this is worth adding.
https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/ticket/4262

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since asking this question, cppcheck has added this feature in response to my suggestion (thanks guys!),

Commit:
https://github.com/danmar/cppcheck/commit/7f6a10599bee61de0c7ee90054808de00b3ae92d

Issue:
http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/cppcheck/ticket/4262

At the time of writing this isn't yet in a release, but I assume it will be in the next release.

Answer (score 8):

The value in the prototype has no meaning to the compiler and is ignored! The function declared above is equivalent to

```
void somefunc(float* arg);
```

and

```
void somefunc(float arg[]);
```

When using C++ you can deal with the size restriction at compile-time using references. If you really mean to have an array of 10 `float`s, you can pass it by reference which will enforce that the size is correct:

```
void somefunc(float (&arg)[10]);
```

However, this will prevent bigger arrays from being passed. You can play with a template forwarding function if you want to pass bigger arrays:

```
void somefunc_intern(float* arg);
template <int Size>
typename std::enable_if<(10 <= Size)>::type
somefunc(float (&arg)[Size]) {
    somefunc_intern(arg);
}
```

Of course, this won't generate a warning but an error if a too small array is passed.

Comment: +1, just to mention that to have the same effect in C, you'd have to use a pointer to array instead of reference to array, something like `void somefunc(float (*arg)[10]);` would do.

Comment: @JensGustedt Still, array pointers will only result in compiler warnings, not errors. I ran the example in my own answer in GCC and Embarcadero and they both produced warnings for incorrect array pointer conversions, but no errors. (And I didn't even need to set -Wall -Wextra in GCC to get the warnings.)

Comment: @Lundin, in C, the only thing that a compiler has to give for a constraint violation is a "diagnostic". A warning fits well into that model, and for what I tested gcc and clang both give such warnings without setting any special option. Generally speaken, a warning from a C compiler is most of the time an indication of a serious problem.

Comment: Warnings are fine, I typically build with -Werror anyway, just some alart to this instance. Im afraid that replacing all 'float arg[10]' with 'float (*arg)[10]' isn't really an option, at least IMHO the inconvenience outweighs the benefits.


@Dietmar, while I understand that this is a style convention and that C won't see the difference between 'float a[10]' and 'float *a', There are tools that check for common errors and correct (but suspicious cases), so I was curious if any exist.

Answer (score 3):

In the **C** language, the `float arg[10]` parameter array bounds are merely stylistic: it is a hint to the programmer, not the compiler. Since C has weak type checking, you can pass any kind of float pointer or array to the function. One may argue and say that a programmer who doesn't read the function documentation before passing parameters to it, is asking for trouble. But there is of course always the potential for accidental bugs.

Good compilers will warn against this. If you have a bad compiler, which does not warn, you should indeed consider using an external static analysis tool, they are always notoriously picky about suspicious type conversions. [Lint](http://www.gimpel.com/html/flex.htm) comes in a Linux version, I haven't used it, but it is known as an affordable alternative to the big and complex ones.

Theoretically, you could write code that will cause the compiler to produce more warnings, but it will obfuscate the program. I wouldn't recommend it, it would look like:

```
void somefunc(float (*arr_ptr)[10])
{
  float* arg = *arr_ptr;
  ...
}

int main()
{
  float ten[10];
  float two[2];

  somefunc(ten);  // warning
  somefunc(&ten); // warning
  somefunc(two);  // warning
  somefunc(&two); // warning

  float (*ten_ptr)[10] = &ten;
  float (*two_ptr)[2] = &two;

  somefunc(ten_ptr) // ok
  somefunc(two_ptr) // warning

}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning of lint as a static code analysis tool. Klockworks is another option. There would be many others and generally static code analysis removes MANY errors from one's code. Here is a recent article with discussion on hacker news. http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/12/24/static-code-analysis/

Comment: @fayyazkl Klockworks, LDRA, Polyspace et al are probably good tools, but the cost at least 10 times more. I wouldn't consider them unless the code is for some form of mission-critical application.

Comment: @fayyazkl, yes - we've run Coverity, PVS-Studio, Clang, CPP-Check and Smatch on our code many times before. However these tools have many false positives to wade through, or need to be managed with comments/pragmas. Since for our software this would almost always be an error, it seems reasonable that some tool, somewhere - could warn of this without going the full static analysis route (which wont work with closed source libs & just headers anyway). So I may try see if I can hobble something together this weekend to do if for me.

Answer (score -1):

A perfectly ordinary C++ compiler will give you a compile error if you use `std::array<N>` instead or C arrays.

So just do that?

Comment: If you author your own headers this is fine, but in many cases the headers are apart of some other library you call into, so its not always possible to just change the types used to suit your purpose. (C++ calling into C library even)

Comment: @ideasman42 but third party headers typically pass arrays as pointers *anyway*, and then there's no way for a tool to extract type/size information. :)

Comment: well, it depends what libs you use, but fair point --- even so, for libs OpenGL functions could be tagged as arguments having a certain size glVertex3fv() is known to be float[3] for eg. This is of course more work and something that needs to be manually defined ontop of the header, so its far from ideal - but for code that uses a lot of opengl its not much work to define sizes for most functions.